# Flutter: How can I make a Random color generator Background

Tags: dart, flutter

> Generate random colors

```
return new RaisedButton(


    padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
    color: Colors.primaries random  List <blue,green>,
```

Comment: You could use: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/random_color

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `Random` class to do that:

But if you want to change the color when button is pressed, you have to use a `StatefulWidget`. A simple example is like below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  List colors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.yellow];
  Random random = new Random();

  int index = 0;

  void changeIndex() {
    setState(() => index = random.nextInt(3));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => changeIndex(),
        child: Text('Click'),
        color: colors[index],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, there is a package called [random_pk](https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterWidgets/blob/master/lib/Episode1_SizedBox/sized_box.dart) by [pawankumar](https://github.com/iampawan/RandomColorWidget), that will give us random color each and every time your app's build method get called.

Answer (score 205):

This is my way to get a random color:

```
Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0)
```

**Note:**
This import is required.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
```

Comment: for beginners: use this import statement `import 'dart:math' as math;`

Comment: @Ascension @Michael Hathi, what is this `import 'dart:math' as math;` doing? I see it is working without adding `math.` before `Random()`

Answer (score 103):

There is an in-built list of material colors in the **Colors** class. You can use it like below

```
var generatedColor = Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)
Colors.primaries[generatedColor]
```

example

```
import 'dart:math';

Icon(
    Icons.account_circle,
    size: 40,
    color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
)
```

Above is the simplest and fastest way to colorize your list with random colors. You don't need to maintain a list of colors.

Comment: Can we get which color has been generated using this method?

Comment: Yes, you can. The generated random `int` decides which colour is being selected. You can use that random `int` in `local variable` and use that again to know what colour you had generated.

Comment: can we skip the repeated color

Comment: There is no built-in logic for it. But with the help of Map, you should be able to record the generated int and skip and retry for a new one.

Answer (score 22):

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';

class Util {
  static Color randomColor() {
    return Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff));
  }
}
```

for opaque color:

```
static Color randomOpaqueColor() {
  return Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)).withAlpha(0xff);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To get random color I do the next:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

final rnd = math.Random();

Color getRandomColor() => Color(rnd.nextInt(0xffffffff));
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way to get tons of colors is using `Random` class with `Color.fromARGB` or `Color.fromRGBO`:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyPage()));
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => new _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  final Random _random = Random();

  Color _color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);

  void changeColor() {
    setState(() {
      _color = Color.fromARGB(
        //or with fromRGBO with fourth arg as _random.nextDouble(),
        _random.nextInt(256),
        _random.nextInt(256),
        _random.nextInt(256),
        _random.nextInt(256),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        onTap: changeColor,
        child: Container(
          color: _color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you use `Color.fromRGBO`:

Fourth argument should be within `0.0` to `1.0` and fortunately we have `_random.nextDouble()` that gives a value between `0.0` to `1.0` randomly.

By the way:

- **R** - Red
- **B** - Blue
- **G** - Green
- **O** - Opacity
- **A** - Alpha

Answer (score 5):

This will generate a different color for the button everytime the build method for the app is called

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:math';

    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // TODO: implement build
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: "Raised Button",
            theme: new ThemeData(
               primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
            ),
            home: new HomePage());
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
    }

    class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      //contains the colours for the circle Avatars
      final List<Color> circleColors = [Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.green];

      Color randomGenerator() {
        return circleColors[new Random().nextInt(2)];
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            child: Text('Click'),
            color: randomGenerator(),
          ),
        );
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

In this way below you can obtain a random color with a one line command without needing any import:

```
 ([...Colors.primaries]..shuffle()).first
```

This is also a great example of cascade notation and spread operators in dart. [Here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) you can find more information about it.

Answer (score 3):

We can use random class for that But there is a **random_color plugin** in the flutter that can help us for generating random color and also we can select high saturation colors with this code:

```
import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';

RandomColor _randomColor = RandomColor();

Color _color = _randomColor.randomColor(
  colorSaturation: ColorSaturation.highSaturation
);
```

And light colors with this code:

```
import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';

RandomColor _randomColor = RandomColor();

Color _color = _randomColor.randomColor(
  colorBrightness: ColorBrightness.light
);
```

For more options read this https://pub.dev/packages/random_color#-readme-tab-

Answer (score 2):

I think we need a separate class for that (you can use static or top-level functions).

**Just don't forget that nextInt**: ["Generates a non-negative random integer uniformly distributed in the range from 0, inclusive, to max, exclusive."](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-math/Random-class.html).
So set "max" to 0x100000000 (0xFFFFFFFF + 1)!

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class RandomColor {
  static const _MAX_VALUE = 0x100000000;
  final _random = Random();

  Color nextColor() => Color(_random.nextInt(_MAX_VALUE));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want distinguishable colors , this method gives 4096 different color with at least 16 level difference :

```
var rnd = Random();
var r = rnd.nextInt(16) * 16;
var g = rnd.nextInt(16) * 16;
var b = rnd.nextInt(16) * 16;
Color color = Color.fromARGB(255, r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to pick random colors from the Colors.primary class:

1- import:

```
import 'dart:math' as math show Random;
```

2- Set value:

```
final color = Colors.primaries[math.Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];
```

3- Use value:

```
backgroundColor: color,
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and best suggested way to do this is:

Step 1: Add dependency in pubspec.yaml
      random_color: ^1.0.3

Step 2: Add import 
      import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';

Step 3: In "color" attribute write
      color: RandomColor().randomColor();

Answer (score 0):

I do the easiest way,

`import 'dart:math';`

and then I use container as avatar

```
             Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(
                    random.nextInt(255),
                    random.nextInt(255),
                    random.nextInt(255),
                    1,
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Icon(Icons.person, size: 60),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
  import 'dart:math';

  Color randomColor() {
      return Color(0xFFFFFFFF & Random().nextInt(0xFFFFFFFF));
  }
```

Comment: There are **15 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with **two hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: @JeremyCaney so? I wrote another option with 'dart: math'

Comment: Please reread my comment carefully, and [edit] your answer to provide an explanation of why you prefer your approach.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Rounded Border with Random Color and Background]

Try Using [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/rounded_image_with_textbg) for Gmail Like effect.
It will generate random color background.
Also support selection widget

```
RoundedImageWithTextAndBG(
    radius: 20,
    isSelected: isSelected,
    uniqueId: textModel[widget.index]['uniqueId'],
    image: (widget.index % 3 == 0)
        ? 'https://picsum.photos/id/${widget.index}/800/800'
        : '',
    text: textModel[widget.index]['name'],
  ),
```